# Send PCM Data via Websocket using AudioProcessor

Tags: audio-streaming, web-audio-api

I am trying to record audio data from the microphone and send it via a websocket as signed 16 bit PCM data with 16000HZ (using javascript in the browser).

I can record the audio, resample it and send it to the speakers:

```js
const audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: false
});
const audioContext = new AudioContext({ 16000 });
const audioStreamSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(audioStream);
audioStreamSource.connect(audioContext.destination);
```

This works, but is it also possible to get the Raw audio data in regular intervals and send it via websocket?

Comment: Depending on the specific formats you need, you can also use the MediaRecorder.  It can output PCM in Matroska on Chromium-based browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [`AudioWorkletProcessor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletProcessor) to access the raw PCM data.

An `AudioWorkletProcessor` runs on the audio thread which means you would need to send the audio data to the main thread or a Web Worker before you can send it over a WebSocket connection since there is no way to setup a WebSocket connection on the audio thread.

Comment: +1, this is a good way.  Alternatively, you can use a regular ScriptProcessorNode.  It's been deprecated for years, but frankly this type of node is so lightweight that it really isn't a problem.  And, that node is probably never going to actually be removed.